# How to apply a function to more than one column with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, numeric

I have a data frame with "revenue" and "quantity".
Both columns are intended to be numeric, yet consist some garbage that should be cleaned before converting to numeric  - such as "," etc.(originally "object").
The following two lines do the trick:

```
data['revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(data['revenue'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x)))
data['quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(data['quantity'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x)))
data.dtypes
```

> revenue            int64
>
> quantity           int64

Now, I wonder if there's a one line code to do so.
I tried the following:

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x)) if x.name in [['revenue','quantity']] else x)
```

That didn't change the object type to Int. Then I tried:

```
data[['revenue','quantity']] = pd.to_numeric(data[['revenue','quantity']].apply(lambda x: re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x)))
```

got the error:

> TypeError: ('expected string or bytes-like object', 'occurred at index revenue')

Any ideas for more efficient code than two lines?

Comment: It would be useful to supply a small sample dataframe for test.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.apply(lambda v: re.sub("[^0-9]", "", v))) if x.name in ['revenue','quantity'] else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually just do

```
for col in ['revenue', 'quantity']:
    data[col] = data[col].apply(function)
```

It's not a one liner, but what you lose in lines you win in readability, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

`data['revenue']` is a series and `apply` is called with the data items of the series. But `data[['revenue', 'quantity']]` is a dataframe, and `apply` is called with the `Series` objects. So twice, with the series `data['revenue']` and then `data['quantity']`. The `x` in `re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x)` is a `Series` object and that's why it fails.

You could change your lambda to

```
lambda s: s.apply(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", x))
```

but the `Dataframe.replace` method accepts regular expressions, so there isn't a need to do `apply` at all.

```
data[['revenue', 'quantity']].replace("[^0-9]", "", regex=True)
```

`to_numeric` doesn't work on dataframes, but `astype` does. So the full conversion would be (assuming you want int64)

```
data[['revenue', 'quantity']] = data[['revenue', 'quantity']].replace(
    "[^0-9]", "", regex=True).astype('int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

My proposition is:

```
data[['revenue', 'quantity']] = data[['revenue', 'quantity']].\
    applymap(lambda v: pd.to_numeric(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", v)))
```

Actually a one-liner, but for readability, due to limited screen width,
split into 2 lines.